# how to write the confirm box code in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How to write the jquery in asp.net2.0, i click the button display confirm box based on requirements

- Confirm box change the buttons(yes,No) and images(warning,information etc) and Heading also 
  pls give me total code, which libraries added and how to write the function in asp.net2.0.
- alert box also displayed based on condition hange the images and heading.

  1. which libraries added and how to write the function

  function:
       $("#confirm_button").click( function() {

  ```
  jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
                                  jAlert('Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results');
                              });
                          });
  ```

  i am click the button code like

**

> ```
> > <input id="confirm_button"
> > type="button" value="Show Confirm" />
> ```

**

Pls help me

THNAK U
HEMANTH

Comment: Explain yourself better, please. It's not clear what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the jquery UI dialog:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#iId").click(function () 
    {
        if (confirm('Your confirm text?')) 
    {
            //confirm='true', (means if you click on ok)
        // your code will go hire
        }
        else
    {
        //confirm='false', (means if you click on cancle)
            // your code will go hire
    }

    });
});
```

Note: You have to keep jquery-ui script file in your code

Comment: above if condition how to change buttons and images confirm('Your confirm text?')  and send me  jquery-ui script file